# NodeJS, pg-promise and multiple connection strings

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I'm running `PostgreSQL 9.6` and `Node.JS` with `pg-promise`.

I once in a while experience downtime due to my connection string is unreachable, but I do have a backup URL which.

Is it possible to use multiple connection strings, so in case one fails it will automatic try the other one? As explained here:
https://paquier.xyz/postgresql-2/postgres-10-multi-host-connstr/

I can't find anything in: https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Connection-Syntax#connection-string.

Or would it be possible to use some build-in Linux hack, so I could create a fake domain which would point to both my real URLs?

Answer (score 0):

It is not yet supported by the underlying driver. See the [related issue](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/1470).

Comment: It seems to be supported by `pg-native`, so guess it could be implemented in `pg-promise`? Test made in https://pastebin.com/LcL79dHk.